# How to remove protection on a range using scripts in Google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to write scripts that can protect and unprotect a range in a Google spreadsheet. The first function works:

```
function AddProtectionToColumn() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = ss.getRange('A:A');
   var protectSs = range.protect().setDescription('Protect column A');  
   var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
   protectSs.addEditor(me);
   protectSs.removeEditors(protectSs.getEditors());
   if (protectSs.canDomainEdit()) {
     protectSs.setDomainEdit(false); 
  }
}
```

but the second function is not working:

```
function RemoveProtectionToColumn() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = ss.getRange('A:A');
   range.protect().remove();
   var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
   protectSs.addEditor(me);
   protectSs.removeEditors(protectSs.getEditors());
   if (protectSs.canDomainEdit()) {
     protectSs.setDomainEdit(false); 
  }
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 8):

The line

```
range.protect().remove();
```

does not have the desired effect because the method `protect` actually *creates* a new protection, which you then remove with `remove`. What you need is to *get the existing protection* with range A:A.

Unfortunately, there is no `getProtection()`  method of a Range object. One has to call [`getProtections`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getProtections(ProtectionType)) on the sheet (or spreadsheet), and then search through the returned array of protections until you find the one you need. You can search either by range (calling `getRange` on each [Protection object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#top_of_page)) or, which is more robust, by description.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // assuming you want the first sheet
var protections = sheet.getProtections();
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  if (protections[i].getDescription() == 'Protect column A') {
    protections[i].remove();
  }
}
```